# Dockerised Laravel 7 app not displaying index page (nginx 502 response)

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I've been trying to just run a Laravel app within a docker container but am having, what I believe, are nginx issues. I've been following a tutorial which firsts gets you to create mysql, nginx and php docker containers. You're then asked to place a test file in `src/public/index.html` which nginx picks up and displays fine. But as soon as I remove everything from the src folder and create a Laravel app within there (new path to index page is `src/public/index.php`) the nginx responds with a 502 bad gateway

No access or error logs are being written to `var/log/nginx` but both the access and error log files exist.

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 81;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx-laravel
    ports:
      - "8088:81"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7.34
    container_name: mysql-laravel
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php-laravel
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

**Nginx works when my directory contains:**
[image: working index.html]

**Nginx does not work when my directory contains:**
[image: laravel app index.php not working]

**nginx container logs**

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
2022-08-25T23:53:31.408201596Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
2022-08-25T23:53:31.411187971Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
2022-08-25T23:53:31.425783138Z 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
2022-08-25T23:53:31.464738763Z 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
2022-08-25T23:53:31.464776263Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
2022-08-25T23:53:31.476458263Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
2022-08-25T23:53:31.479142054Z /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022-08-25T23:53:31.549867721Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022-08-25T23:53:31.549892013Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.22.0
2022-08-25T23:53:31.549894305Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 
2022-08-25T23:53:31.549896180Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.10.104-linuxkit
2022-08-25T23:53:31.549897888Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022-08-25T23:53:31.550830388Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022-08-25T23:53:31.551071888Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2022-08-25T23:53:31.551080305Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2022-08-25T23:53:31.551163930Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2022-08-25T23:53:31.551679305Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2022-08-25T23:53:31.551763680Z 2022/08/25 23:53:31 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2022-08-25T23:53:58.719467761Z 2022/08/25 23:53:58 [error] 35#35: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.20.0.2:9001", host: "localhost:8088"
2022-08-25T23:53:58.719932636Z 172.20.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2022:23:53:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: is there anything in the container logs?

Comment: Have updated the question with the nginx container logs

Comment: That says "connection refused" check the php container log as well to see if it's still running or if it crashed (for whatever reason)

Comment: Seems to only say:


[26-Aug-2022 04:21:44] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[26-Aug-2022 04:21:44] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Comment: Try running `docker-compose exec php /bin/bash` and then check your `www.conf` (might be in /usr/local/php or somewhere in there) to make sure that php-fpm is listening on the correct port. The default port is 9000 so if you haven't changed it then that's the one it would listen to.

Comment: Ok so I wasn't able to find any `conf` file that gave the option of a default port so I ended up changing my exposed port for the php container back to 9000 assuming what you said was correct (and I just couldn't find it). Everything is working now

I'm not sure how to label your 'way of thinking' as the catalyst toward the answer